# recurring payment to already running paypal script

Tags: php, paypal

I have seen many related questions but didn't find any answer.

I have successfully implemented transactions through paypal but now I am asked to implement recurring payments through paypal. I have searched but couldn't find any material that can help me how to implement this.

First what I have implemented.
I ask user to select amount. User selects amount, I transfer user to paypal where he enters his information and do transaction.
After successful transaction I show user the transaction id and stores ipn information and user information in my database.

Now I want to give an option to user to select recurring payment with yes or no. If user selects recurring payment then his recurring payment will be done with the amount that he selects above.

Now I want to know:

1. What to change in my already running paypal script to have recurring paypal payments?
2. recurring details will be asked at time of payment.
3. What additional parameters to be sent now to have this?
4. How to test it on already running application?
5. What parameters paypal will send back to me as ipn?
6. I have tried to understand from paypal website but couldn't.

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring

Comment: please provide your already running paypal script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*In this list there are all the Docs you need. theese are not casual links taken from the net, theese are a set of links i have collected when i had to do exactly the same thing you are trying to do now. ;)*

- [Handling Recurring Payments (Official)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/)
- [Subscriptions and Recurring Payments Variables](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside) <sup>( **3** )</sup>
- [Advanced Techniques - \"Subscribe\" Button HTML Code](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside) <sup>( **1** )</sup>
- [PDN - Subscriptions Overview](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/tech-overview-subscriptions-outside)
- [Adding PayPal Checkout to Your 3rd-party Shopping Cart](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside)
- [HTML Variables for Website Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) <sup>( **3** )</sup>
- [Canceling Individual Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/#id08ADF700X44) <sup>( **2** )</sup>
- [IPN and PDT Variables](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables) <sup>( **3** )</sup>
- [Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator) <sup>( **4** )</sup>
- [IPN Testing](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/) <sup>( **4** )</sup>
- [Payment status – what does it mean?](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ1211&topicID=PAYING&m=TCI) <sup>( **5** )</sup>
- [Sample Code](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/code-samples/)

happy coding. ;)

Comment: @user198989 thanks for the check, i have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an instant sample code using PHP to create recurring payment using paypal

[Instant paypal recurring payment code with NVP PHP](http://tmsajin.blogspot.com/2011/10/recurring-payment-code.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the solution from the following reference url's.....

```
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/handling-recurring-payments-with-paypal-subscriptions-and-ipn/5331883

http://help.wildapricot.com/display/DOC/Recurring+payments+with+PayPal+Standard 

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-recurring-billing-overview-outside
```

Comment: @john2103 thanks boss for your response. But I think you didn't read my question carefully that what Am I demanding........... I visited your providing links already... But Thanks for giving attention on my question

Answer (score 0):

Try The following Codes :

```
$paypalObj = new paypal_class();

$itemName = My Product";
$itemNumber = $itemName . " - Premium ($amount$)";

$paypalObj->paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';// testing paypal url
//$paypalObj->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';// Live paypal url

$paypalObj->add_field('cmd','_xclick-subscriptions');
$paypalObj->add_field('txn_type', "recurring_payment");
$paypalObj->add_field('product_name', "My Product Subscription - Monthly( $$amount )");
$paypalObj->add_field('desc', "Magic Niche Finder Subscription - Monthly( $$amount )");

$paypalObj->add_field('business', "test@yahoo.com");

$paypalObj->add_field('return', "http://".$serverName . "/buy-now.php");
$paypalObj->add_field('cancel_return', "http://".$serverName. "/return.php?action=cancel");
$paypalObj->add_field('notify_url', "http://" . $serverName . "/return.php?action=ipn");

$paypalObj->add_field('src', "1");
$paypalObj->add_field('sra', "1");
$paypalObj->add_field('a3', "$amount");
$paypalObj->add_field('t3', "M");
$paypalObj->add_field('p3', "1");
//$paypalObj->add_field('no_note', "1");
$paypalObj->add_field('currency_code', "USD");

$paypalObj->add_field('first_name', $firstName);
$paypalObj->add_field('last_name', $lastName);

$paypalObj->submit_paypal_post();
```

Comment: @john2103 hahaha nice try again. But before putting my question I searched the whole stackoverflow.......... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to start creating Recurring Payment Profiles for your users.

The documentation for that can be found [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments#id08652L010BL).  I also came across a [PHP Script](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_php.txt) that looks like it has all the code in it you'll need.

Comment: I have visited these and have implemented the code... But not found answer. I am having error of create profile failed...

Comment: That means the curl_exec is returning a failure.  I'd double check the API docs to make sure you're calling the method with the right parameters.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand from your question, i think paypal's Preapproval API definitely will be able to help you. I am currently working on this recurring payment as well and i manage to meet up with a paypal staff to discuss about their formula and this is what they have recommended.

You can read more about their API from my link below to understand how pre-approval works and how it can help you automatically deduct money from client's paypal account as long as they do not enter their paypal account to manually cancel the option after they opt for it.

https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1419

Answer (score 0):

**Q>** What to change in my already running paypal script to have recurring paypal payments?
**A>** It depends on your current script. For example, if you have used Paypal-hosted *Buy Now* button, you might want to do the same for the *Subscribe* button. After doing this, you will see the differences between HTML forms you need to submit. There are just a few differences, but you either need to make some Javascript hacks to ensure you're sending the right stuff, or create separate forms.

Recurring details will be asked at time of payment.

Not sure if this was a question, but if so, I don't understand what is being asked here :(

**Q**> What additional parameters to be sent now to have this?
**A**> As I answered in my previous question, it depends on how you are doing it currently. `<INPUT type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" ...` will likely be different if you use hosted buttons, you might also need to send recurring payment details, etc.

**Q>** How to test it on already running application?
**A>** The same way you would test any other IPN payment.

**Q>** What parameters paypal will send back to me as ipn?
**A>** I am getting one extra parameter, `subscr_id`. But it's probably best to look at the [manual](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/subscriptions/Appx-ipn_subscription_variables.html).